# When is it safe to free sockaddr passed to bind?

Tags: c, sockets

Bind expects a pointer to `struct sockaddr` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html). Is it safe to free this structure immediately after the call to `bind` or is it safe to free this only when the socket is closed?

If it is safe to free the structure immediately after the call to `bind`, does the kernel keep a copy of the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can free it immediately after the call.

Usually the `sockaddr` or `sockaddr_in` is declared on the stack. But if you're passing addresses around by pointer, you're ok free it immediately after `bind` returns.  Same holds true for other socket functions like `connect` and `sendto`.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to free. As you can see in the comments to the [Linux source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c#L1765) for the syscall, the structure is copied by the kernel.

> - We move the socket address to kernel space before we call  *    the
>   protocol layer (having also checked the address is ok).